# Mutli Tenant App Time Zones rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, timezone

I have a multi tenant rails app and some models have a date field.  Is it possible to have a different time zone for each record.  Would I do something like add a field called time zone then do `Date.somemethodthatsetstimezone(timezone).now()`?  Sorry if this is a bad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is yes - but make sure you know what you're doing.

You'll want to take a look at [ActiveSupport::TimeZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) and [ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html). ActiveSupport::TimeZone provides time zones as value objects access as strings. For example, you can store the string `'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'` on a time_zone column in your model (let's say `@project`), then retrieve the time zone instance with `ActiveSupport::TimeZone[@project.time_zone]`.

You can set the time zone of the current process with something like `Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'`. Rails also allows you to configure the time zone for your app in the application config.

You can call `Time.zone.now` to return the current time (as an instance of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`) in the time zone to which the current ruby process is set.

You can call `Time.now.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')` to get the current time in the given time zone.

You can even set the time zone for a block of code:

```
Time.use_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)') do
  # do stuff in eastern time

  Time.now 
  # => current eastern time 
end
```

This method allows you to set the time zone for an entire rails request using the time zone from your model and an around filter:

```
around_filter :project_time_zone

# actions use project's configured time zone

private

def project_time_zone(&block)
  Time.use_zone(@project.time_zone, &block)
end
```

One of these approaches should get you what you need.